Flutter : how to change DropdownButton splash raduis
Im using DropdownButton.
Problem : DropdownButton has no proprety named splashraduis.
Question : How to change splashraduis for a click? splashraduis is the raduis of the  splash that the element make when clicked.
I tried wrapping in both GestionDetector() and Inkwell() .Both dont have splashraduis property .
Any help would be appreciated.

You can change it this way using borderRadius:
DropdownButton<String>(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  items: [
    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: 'Option 1',
      child: Text('Option 1'),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: 'Option 2',
      child: Text('Option 2'),
    ),
  ],
  onChanged: (String? value) {},
)


Does this actually change the splash raduis ? because PopUpMenuButton has splashRadius property.
